# I am getting Error 1053 when I start or stop my windows services

Tags: windows-services

Is there any manual ways to debug it like doing some changes with scripting ? Without installing something and do registry scans all ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `"Attach to process"` feature of visual studio to debug windows services. Checkout [this post.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

anyway, the cause of this problem is : your service uses a local account.
you can find a hotfix here : http://forums.isaserver.org/m_2002049399/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#2002049399

stephane Halimi